# why my colorbar gets messed up in groupplot environment in pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots, groupplots

I have a single colorbar graph that looks like this:
[image]

As soon as I add a similar graph using `groupplot` the ticks and the tick labels of the colorbar disappear:
[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this? Here is the complete code of `groupplot` I am using:

````
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}%fitting functions
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,patterns}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}


\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,1000 sep={}}



\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\pgfplotsset{label style={font=\Large},
            tick label style={font=\Large}}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

%%%%%%%% left channel

\begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=1 by 3,
    vertical sep=7em},
%   axis x line=bottom,
%   axis y line=center,
    width=10cm,
    height=7cm,
    ticks=none,
    axis line style={draw=none},
    xmin=-35,xmax=35,
    ymin=-2,ymax=47,
]

\nextgroupplot[
    declare function={k(\x)=max(-12.5,min(-8,-4.5*\x/20.45-6.53));
    l(\x)=max(-14,min(-10,-4*\x/20.45-8.69));},
    declare function={f(\x)=max(8,min(12.5,4.5*\x/20.45+6.53));
    g(\x)=max(10,min(14,4*\x/20.45+8.69));},
    view={0}{90},
    colorbar,
    colormap={whiteblue}{
        color(0cm)=(green!10); color(1cm)=(green)},
    colorbar style={
        ylabel={channel width [mm]},
        yticklabel={$\pgfmathparse{-1*\tick}%
        \pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult$}}
]
%%%%%left

\begin{scope}  
\clip[variable=\x] plot[samples at={-0.2,6.7,27.15,37.3}] ({k(\x)},\x) -- plot[samples at={37.3,27.15,6.7,-0.2}] ({l(\x)},\x) -- cycle;
\addplot3[surf,shader=flat,point meta={l(y)-k(y)},domain=-15:-5,
    domain y=-1:40] {x};
\end{scope}

%%%%%right

\begin{scope}  
\clip[variable=\x] plot[samples at={-0.2,6.7,27.15,37.3}] ({f(\x)},\x) -- plot[samples at={37.3,27.15,6.7,-0.2}] ({g(\x)},\x) -- cycle;
\addplot3[surf,shader=flat,point meta={f(y)-g(y)},domain=5:15,
    domain y=-1:40] {x};
\end{scope}


\nextgroupplot[
    declare function={a(\x)=max(-13.5,min(-8,-5.5*\x/20.45-6.2));
    b(\x)=max(-14,min(-10,-4*\x/20.45-8.69));},
    declare function={c(\x)=max(8,min(13.5,5.5*\x/20.45+6.2));
    d(\x)=max(10,min(14,4*\x/20.45+8.69));},
    view={0}{90},
    colorbar,
    colormap={whiteblue}{
        color(0cm)=(blue!10); color(1cm)=(blue)},
    colorbar style={
        ylabel={channel width [mm]},
        yticklabel={$\pgfmathparse{-1*\tick}%
        \pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult$}}
]

\begin{scope}  
\clip[variable=\x] plot[samples at={-0.2,6.7,27.15,37.3}] ({a(\x)},\x) -- plot[samples at={37.3,27.15,6.7,-0.2}] ({b(\x)},\x) -- cycle;
\addplot3[surf,shader=flat,point meta={b(y)-a(y)},domain=-15:-5,
    domain y=-1:40] {x};
\end{scope}


\begin{scope}  
\clip[variable=\x] plot[samples at={-0.2,6.7,27.15,37.3}] ({c(\x)},\x) -- plot[samples at={37.3,27.15,6.7,-0.2}] ({d(\x)},\x) -- cycle;
\addplot3[surf,shader=flat,point meta={c(y)-d(y)},domain=5:15,
    domain y=-1:40] {x};
\end{scope}



\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}```
````

Comment: Please note that the `group size=1 by 3` should be `1 by 2`. That is not the cause of the problem though.

Comment: You can just edit the question to fix the group size.

Comment: You have `ticks=none` in your options. If you drop this key, the ticks come back, as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set in the options of the group plot `ticks=none`. Assuming that you only want ticks for the color bars, you can install them there with `ticks=major`, say.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}


\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,1000 sep={}}



\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\pgfplotsset{label style={font=\Large},
            tick label style={font=\Large}}



\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

%%%%%%%% left channel

\begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=1 by 2,
    vertical sep=7em},
%   axis x line=bottom,
%   axis y line=center,
    width=10cm,
    height=7cm,
    ticks=none,
    axis line style={draw=none},
    xmin=-35,xmax=35,
    ymin=-2,ymax=47,
]

\nextgroupplot[
    declare function={k(\x)=max(-12.5,min(-8,-4.5*\x/20.45-6.53));
    l(\x)=max(-14,min(-10,-4*\x/20.45-8.69));},
    declare function={f(\x)=max(8,min(12.5,4.5*\x/20.45+6.53));
    g(\x)=max(10,min(14,4*\x/20.45+8.69));},
    view={0}{90},
    colorbar,
    colormap={whiteblue}{
        color(0cm)=(green!10); color(1cm)=(green)},
    colorbar style={ticks=major,
        ylabel={channel width [mm]},
        yticklabel={$\pgfmathparse{-1*\tick}%
        \pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult$}}
]
%%%%%left

\begin{scope}  
\clip[variable=\x] plot[samples at={-0.2,6.7,27.15,37.3}] ({k(\x)},\x) -- plot[samples at={37.3,27.15,6.7,-0.2}] ({l(\x)},\x) -- cycle;
\addplot3[surf,shader=flat,point meta={l(y)-k(y)},domain=-15:-5,
    domain y=-1:40] {x};
\end{scope}

%%%%%right

\begin{scope}  
\clip[variable=\x] plot[samples at={-0.2,6.7,27.15,37.3}] ({f(\x)},\x) -- plot[samples at={37.3,27.15,6.7,-0.2}] ({g(\x)},\x) -- cycle;
\addplot3[surf,shader=flat,point meta={f(y)-g(y)},domain=5:15,
    domain y=-1:40] {x};
\end{scope}


\nextgroupplot[
    declare function={a(\x)=max(-13.5,min(-8,-5.5*\x/20.45-6.2));
    b(\x)=max(-14,min(-10,-4*\x/20.45-8.69));},
    declare function={c(\x)=max(8,min(13.5,5.5*\x/20.45+6.2));
    d(\x)=max(10,min(14,4*\x/20.45+8.69));},
    view={0}{90},
    colorbar,
    colormap={whiteblue}{
        color(0cm)=(blue!10); color(1cm)=(blue)},
    colorbar style={ticks=major,
        ylabel={channel width [mm]},
        yticklabel={$\pgfmathparse{-1*\tick}%
        \pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult$}}
]

\begin{scope}  
\clip[variable=\x] plot[samples at={-0.2,6.7,27.15,37.3}] ({a(\x)},\x) -- plot[samples at={37.3,27.15,6.7,-0.2}] ({b(\x)},\x) -- cycle;
\addplot3[surf,shader=flat,point meta={b(y)-a(y)},domain=-15:-5,
    domain y=-1:40] {x};
\end{scope}


\begin{scope}  
\clip[variable=\x] plot[samples at={-0.2,6.7,27.15,37.3}] ({c(\x)},\x) -- plot[samples at={37.3,27.15,6.7,-0.2}] ({d(\x)},\x) -- cycle;
\addplot3[surf,shader=flat,point meta={c(y)-d(y)},domain=5:15,
    domain y=-1:40] {x};
\end{scope}



\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want ticks everywhere, drop `ticks=none`.

Comment: That works, thanks. How would you draw the axis lines around the colorbar in the groupplot similar to the single plot?

Comment: @Gagik Just add `axis line style={draw},` to `colorbar style`. In general, pgf keys get inherited. Since you set `axis line style={draw=none},` in the ambient group plot, this style gets inherited by the color bars. So if you do not like that, you can always change the style locally to what you want.

Comment: It works perfectly. Thanks a lot.